# SAS Enterprise Guide - customising log results after submitting code

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

The EG log is quite messy for even the simplest piece of SAS code.  For example submitting the following code:

```
data _null_;
run;
```

Will produce the following log:

```
1                                                          The SAS System                              11:12 Wednesday, May 13, 2015

1          ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
2          OPTIONS PAGENO=MIN;
3          %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL='Program';
4          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH='';
5          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME='';
6          %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
7          
8          ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
9          OPTIONS DEV=ACTIVEX;
10         GOPTIONS XPIXELS=0 YPIXELS=0;
11         FILENAME EGSR TEMP;
12         ODS tagsets.sasreport13(ID=EGSR) FILE=EGSR STYLE=HtmlBlue
12       ! STYLESHEET=(URL="file:///C:/Program%20Files/SASHome/SASEnterpriseGuide/5.1/Styles/HtmlBlue.css") NOGTITLE NOGFOOTNOTE
12       ! GPATH=&sasworklocation ENCODING=UTF8 options(rolap="on");
NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR
13         
14         GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;


15         data _null_;
16         run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


17         
18         GOPTIONS NOACCESSIBLE;
19         %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL=;
20         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH=;
21         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME=;
22         %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
23         
24         ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
25         ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
26         
27         
28         QUIT; RUN;
29
```

That's quite a lot of completely useless info being returned, that obscures the only part of the log I want to see (lines 15:16):

```
15         data _null_;
16         run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Is there any way to change this default behaviour?  I've poked through the options and nothing jumped out at me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools > Options... > Results General > Uncheck "Show Generated Wrapper Code in SAS Log"